# I can't get div to center in HTML

Tags: html

I have some HTML code with a `div` setting up a picture gallery. I ma trying to get it into the centre but it won't go.

This works to put it on the left:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
```

Why does this not work. I have tried:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="text-align: center; width: 600px; height: 300px;">

<div id="slider1_container" align="center" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;">
```

Comment: There's no property align.

Comment: align:center is not the style property you need to use <div id="slider1_contaniner" align="center">

Comment: In your real code, please put your css in a separate file. Those inline style declarations are a real nuisance for maintenance and updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually center a block level element (as it occupies the full horizontal space available to it). You have to first give it a width then you can use an `margin: 0 auto;` to shift it into position like this:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vxtLyd7s/)

If you are positioning an element inside another positioned element you can use an absolute position of -50% to center a fixed width element like this:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; width: 600px; margin-left: -300px;"></div>
</div>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vxtLyd7s/1/)

On the other hand if you want to center the inline content of `slider1_container`, you can use `text-align: center;` like this:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="text-align: center; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
```

Comment: You can include that he can center elements with `position: absolute` (inside of another container) giving it: `left: 50%` and `margin-left: half/element's width`.

Comment: Thanks - the only thing that worked was the left: 50%; margin-left: -300px; I am going to keep looking at it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

try giving this

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code `align: center` won't work for div tags. 
You need to give `margin: 0 auto;` **along** with a `width`

Margin property won't work if width is set to auto.